# Dynamic value of parsed XML response with namespaces

Tags: paw-app

I have the following response for a request using Paw

```
<string xmlns="http://www.chemspider.com/">46c870ad-0198-4a15-95f5-d517f106fcbc</string>
```

And now I want to re-use the value in a second request. For this I use a dynamic value of the parsed response body and use "string" as keypath. But this doesn't work and I assume it's because of the namespace of the XML element.

Does anyone know how to specify the keypath?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution.

```
string.txt
```